# Rake tasks inside gem not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I have implemented what [edebill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27603/edebill) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444867/19224) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878640/including-rake-tasks-in-gems).

If I point to the gem in the usual way, with it installed in my environment

```
gem 'activerecord_datawarehouse'
```

rake -T does not show my rake tasks, but if I point directly to the gem source code, like

```
gem 'activerecord_datawarehouse', :path => "/home/acras/code/activerecord_datawarehouse"
```

It shows and rake tasks work perfectly.

What could I be missing here? I did double checked and the installed gem is the same that I have in the source code.

Comment: Sorry for the errant answer - I can't get it to work either.

Comment: Ah - figured it out! See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it on my end. In the gemspec, you need to include the rake tasks files as well, not just the lib files:

Instead of:

```
  s.files = Dir['lib/**/*.rb']
```

Use:

```
  s.files = Dir['lib/**/*.rb'] + Dir['tasks/*.rake']
```

Comment: Please note that my gem DO work, what do not work are the rake tasks inside the gem. They are not found, but all classes from the gem works perfectly in both ways of declaring it.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand. See the revision.