# Why is this gem not adding rake tasks to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, bundler

We have [a gem](https://github.com/dmcouncil/gem_fresh) which runs via a Rake task. The task is defined in `lib/tasks/<namespace>.rake`. After reading [Rake tasks inside gem not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17811260/306084) I confirmed that the `.gemspec` includes the file defining the task; there is also [a railtie which should be including the tasks](https://github.com/dmcouncil/gem_fresh/blob/pjm/rake-task/lib/gem_fresh/railtie.rb) as suggested in [including rake tasks in gems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1878640/306084). And yet our Rails 4.1 application doesn't seem to load the Rake task.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was not with the gem, but with the way it was included in the app.

In the `Gemfile`, this works and includes the rake task:

```
gem 'gem_fresh'
```

This works but *doesn't* include the rake task:

```
group :development do
  gem 'gem_fresh'
end
```

This seems to be due to how Bundler requires gems in Rails apps. [From the documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.11/groups.html):

> By default, a Rails generated app calls `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)` in your application.rb, which links the groups in your Gemfile to the Rails environment.

If for some reason that `Rails.env` argument wasn't evaluating to include the `:development` group, which seems to be the case when I call `rake -T`, the gem wouldn't be `Bundler.require`-d, and the rake tasks wouldn't be loaded.

The fact that it isn't including the `:development` group seems to be an odd Bundler "gotcha", but at least now I know that moving it to the default group solves the issue and it's not a problem with the gem.

Answer (score 6):

I just successfully tested your gem and I can see no problem with the rake tasks in it:

- I added `gem_fresh` to the Gemfile and ran `bundle`, the gem installed
- Immediately I could see the rake present in the list of rakes:

  ```
  $ rake -T outdated
  rake gem_fresh:outdated  # outdated
  ```
- Then I updated the `railtie.rb` file to use the `load` method to load the rake defined in `lib/task/metrics.rake` and searched the available rakes again:

  ```
  # lib/gem_fresh/railtie.rb:
  rake_tasks do
    namespace :gem_fresh do
      desc "outdated"
      task :outdated => :environment do
        GemFresh::Reporter.new.report
      end
    end

    load "tasks/metrics.rake"
  end 

  $ rake -T outdated
  rake gem_fresh:outdated     # outdated
  rake metrics:outdated_gems  # display outdated gem version metrics
  ```

So, I can see no problem with your gem. Both methods in railtie (inline rake as well as using the load method) seem to work OK. The only difference I noticed is that I tested this on rails 4.2 but I rather doubt that would make a difference.

**Did you put the gem into your Gemfile?** If I remove it from there, I indeed see no `gem_fresh` rakes defined.

Comment: You led me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the project requiring the gem had a rake file, and the gem I was requiring had the same name when I changed the name of the rake file I could see the tasks in the project.

my_gem had lib/tasks/XXXX.rake and my_proj also had lib/tasks/XXXX.rake,
after I changed my_gem XXXX.rake to YYYY.rake I managed to list and use the tasks in YYYY.rake